# Conectando C# ao SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql, connectionstring

Estou tentando conectar um programa ao banco de dados hospedado no SQL Server, mas estou tendo problemas..

Quando o programa é executado, a tela de login é a primeira a aparecer, e dela preciso abrir a segunda tela com opções para adicionar pagamentos e etc no banco de dados..

Meu banco de dados tem 3 "roles" onde cada um tem permissões de alterar pagamento, alterar contrato, etc.. São eles: Owner, Manager e Associate, e 3 usuarios com as devidas senhas aos quais já dei os devidos "roles".. São eles: mrlee(Owner), mngr(Manager) e asso(Associate).

Como consigo conectar ao banco de dados através desses usuários que criei no SQL Server e "manter" essa conexão quando abrir a outra janela do programa que é onde farei as alterações? Preciso manter a conexão pra que cada usuário só faça o que for permitido no seu "role".

É minha primeira vez tentando conectar um programa à um banco de dados e estou tendo muita dificuldade..

O nome da DataBase é ML074539

A janela de login está assim:

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void loginBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (usernameBox.Text == "" || passwordBox.Password == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please, check if you've entered your username and password.");
        } else
        {
            using (SqlConnection dataConnection = new SqlConnection())
            {
                try
                {
                    string userName = usernameBox.Text;
                    string password = passwordBox.Password;

                    SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
                    builder.DataSource = ".\\MSSQLSERVER";
                    builder.InitialCatalog = "ML074539";
                    builder.UserID = userName;
                    builder.Password = password;
                    dataConnection.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString;
                    dataConnection.Open();


                    MultiLeaseWindow mw = new MultiLeaseWindow();
                    mw.Show();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unexpected error:" + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

MultiLeaseWindow é onde está o formulário para adicionar o pagamento e etc..

Quando aperto o botão "Login", independente do User Name e Password que eu usar(desde que não deixe em branco), recebo um erro falando que o servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível e etc..

Já pesquisei bastante, mas ainda não achei uma resposta que eu consiga fazer funcionar.

Comment: O `InitialCatalog` é o nome da base da dados no SQL Server e o `DataSource` deveria ser `"ML074539\\MSSQLSERVER"`, caso sua instância do SQL Server seja a padrão (MSSQLSERVER). Caso seja instância Express, o nome padrão da instância é SQLEXPRESS.

Comment: Se entendi bem, o nome da base de dados no SQL é ML074539 mesmo.. É onde estão as tabelas e etc. Uso o nome do banco de dados no DataSource também? Antes da instância do SQL? (A instância é a padrão sim.. MSSQLSERVER, pelo que vi nos serviços do Windows)

Comment: E qual é o nome do computador? Você tem que substituir o `.` em `".\\MSSQLSERVER"` pelo nome do computador-servidor SQL Server, senão o app vai tentar se conectar ao próprio computador onde o app roda.

Comment: Não, use `ML074539` no `InitialCatalog`, então

Comment: O app está rodando no mesmo computador que o banco de dados (e preciso que isso aconteça porque vou entregar esse projeto no curso, e lá já vai ser outro computador..). Mesmo assim, preciso mudar?  O nome do computador é DESKTOP-066MJ19

Comment: O Windows Firewall está ligado? Se estiver, experimente desligá-lo.

Comment: Desliguei e continuou com o mesmo erro..
Só uma dúvida, se eu conseguir conectar ao banco de dados, essa conexão vai ser mantida quando a janela de login for fechada e a MultiLeaseWindow for aberta?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79911/discussion-between-marcelo-uchimura-and-rafael399).

Comment: E aí, conseguiu progredir um pouco após o chat?

Comment: Consegui pensar em outro jeito de fazer que achei mais facil, hahaha!
Fiz a tabela "Usuarios" no banco de dados e usei ela pra checar as credenciais e atribuir um Level de acesso pra o usuário que logou.. Com isso criei um User no app com essas propriedades e passei ele pra tela do MultiLease, aí consigo checar qual o "acesso" dele a cada tarefa que vai ser executada pra ver se ele possui o level de acesso necessário pra executar essa tarefa. Valeeu pela ajuda!!!

Comment: Boa cara, vai fundo, qquer coisa só dar um grito. Abs!